# Facing trouble to fetch mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a dynamic category with sub-category in navigation Menu. But I want show only those categories who have at least one sub-category.
what should I have to use query.

[image: Database image]

Comment: are you expecting something like `SELECT CATEGORY from table group by category having count(sub_category) > 1`

Comment: @PK20 - Thank you Friend.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
SELECT CATEGORY from table 
group by category 
having count(sub_category) > 1
```